# How to set i18n default translation options

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I'm using `i18next` with `React`.
I have some translations like these:

```
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH', {maxLength: 255}) // 90% <br/>
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH', {maxLength: 100}) // 5% <br/>
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH', {maxLength: 32}) // 5% <br/>
```

Since the value of `maxLength` is 255 most of the time, so I prefer to make it the default value for all translations, so my code can be like this:

```
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH') // maxLength will be 255 by default <br/>
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH', {maxLength: 100})  <br/>
t('FIELD_MAX_LENGTH', {maxLength: 32}) <br/>
```

Is this possible for `i18next`, if yes how to do it?

Thank guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can define defaultVariables in the [interpolation options](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#all-interpolation-options),
like this:

```
i18next.init({
  // ... your current options
  interpolation: {
    defaultVariables: { maxLength: 255 }
  }
})
```